# Почему не срабатывает Tkinter при автозапуске скрипта на Kali из systemctl

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tkinter

Есть скрипт на питоне, который отлично работает на Kali, если его запускать через контекстное меню. Но при попытке запуска через systemctl сервис - вылетает ошибка, связанная с Tkinter. Гугление ничего не дало(или я недопонял). Прошу не кидаться тапками - с Kali, да и вообще с линуксом работаю недавно.

Скрипт на питоне:

```
import json
import os
import pickle
import sys
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

import requests

import Variables
import streams


def load_settings():
    with open("settings.txt", "r", encoding="UTF8") as setings:
        f = setings.read()
        lines = f.split(';')
        print(lines[0])
        Variables.ip = lines[0]


def on_start():
    if os.path.exists('data.pickle'):
        with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:  
            try:
                data_new = pickle.load(f)
            except:
                data_new = []
                pass
        Variables.list_of_saved_data = data_new
        entry.delete(1.0, END)
        for element in Variables.list_of_saved_data:
            entry.insert(1.0, element + '\n')
        print(Variables.list_of_saved_data)
    else:
        with open('data.pickle', "w"):
            pass
    load_settings()


def general_title_state():
    value1 = []
    if Variables.code_of_response_server == 200:
        Variables.root_title = "My notes sync LAN (connected)"
        root.title(Variables.root_title)
        val = entry1.get(0, END)
        value1 = list(val)
        # value1.reverse()
        # for i in enumerate(val):
        #     if val[0] == '':
        #          del val[0]

        # value1 = val
        print("value = " + str(val))
        if Variables.list_of_get_data != value1:
            write_server_data_to_entry()

    else:
        Variables.root_title = "My notes sync LAN (no connect)"
        root.title(Variables.root_title)
        pass
    pass
    root.after(2000, general_title_state)


def write_server_data_to_entry():
    b = Variables.list_of_get_data
    entry1.delete(0, END)
    for i in b:
        entry1.insert(END, i)
    # for index, element in enumerate(b):
    #     if index < len(b) and element != '':
    #         entry1.insert(1.0, element )


def write_local_data():
    val = list((entry.get(1.0, END)).split())
    val.reverse()
    Variables.list_of_saved_data = val
    with open('data.pickle', "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(Variables.list_of_saved_data, f)
    root.after(2000, write_local_data)


def set_data():
    try:
        dict = {}
        lis = list((entry.get(1.0, END)).split('\n'))
        if lis[-1] == '\n' or lis[-1] == '':
            del lis[-1]
        for index, val in enumerate(lis):
            dict[index] = val
        print(dict)
        r = requests.get("http://" + str(Variables.ip) + "/data_json_set", json=(dict))
        if r.status_code == 200:
            print("set_data " + str(lis))
    except:
        print("EXcept of set data!!!")
        pass


def onSelect(val):
    sender = val.widget
    idx = sender.curselection()
    try:
        value = sender.get(idx)
    except:
        value = ""
        pass
    from tkinter import Tk
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(value)
    print(value)


def get_clipboard_text(event):
    from tkinter import Tk
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    s = root.clipboard_get()
    entry.insert(END, s)


def view_my_notes(event):
    t = Toplevel()
    t.wm_title("My notes")
    l = Text(t, font=("Arial Bold", 12))
    l.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=5, pady=5)
    aaa = entry2.get(1.0, END)
    l.insert(1.0, aaa)


root = Tk()
root.iconphoto(True, PhotoImage(file='icon.png'))
root.title(Variables.root_title)
root.geometry('300x155-0-40')
root.resizable(True, True)

f_top = Frame(root)
f_bot = Frame(root)
f_my = Frame(root)
f_top.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
f_bot.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
f_my.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
entry = Text(f_top, font=("Arial Bold", 12), height=2, width=27)
entry.bind('<Button-3>', get_clipboard_text)
entry.pack(fill=X, expand=True)
button = Button(f_top, text="Send", width=2, command=set_data)
button.pack(fill=X, expand=True)
entry1 = Listbox(f_bot, font=("Arial Bold", 12), height=4)
entry1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", onSelect)
entry1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
entry2 = Text(f_bot, font=("Arial Bold", 12), height=2)
entry2.bind('<Button-3>', view_my_notes)
entry2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

th1 = Thread(target=streams.get_data, daemon=True)
th1.start()
root.after(0, on_start)
root.after(0, general_title_state)
root.after(0, write_local_data)
root.mainloop()
```

Сама ошибка:

```
test.service - My test
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-12-05 19:24:19 +05; 1min 9s ago
   Duration: 638ms
    Process: 3427 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.10 /home/qwerty/clients1/client_main.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 3427 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 502ms

дек 05 19:24:19 kali01 systemd[1]: Started My test.
дек 05 19:24:19 kali01 python3.10[3427]: Traceback (most recent call last):
дек 05 19:24:19 kali01 python3.10[3427]:   File "/home/qwerty/clients1/client_main.py", line 138, in <module>
дек 05 19:24:19 kali01 python3.10[3427]:     root = Tk()
дек 05 19:24:19 kali01 python3.10[3427]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
дек 05 19:24:19 kali01 python3.10[3427]:     self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, >
дек 05 19:24:19 kali01 python3.10[3427]: _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
дек 05 19:24:19 kali01 systemd[1]: test.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
дек 05 19:24:19 kali01 systemd[1]: test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
lines 1-17/17 (END)
```

Comment: Довольно логично, что у фоновых служб не бывает экрана, на котором они могли бы что-нибудь рисовать

Comment: Так как запускать тогда нужно?

Comment: Например, штатным механизмом автозапуска, предоставляемым используемой вами средой рабочего стола

Comment: Пробовал - не срабатывает. И через bash-скрипт не срабатывает ниоткуда, кроме терминала. Из терминала все работает на ура. Что на прямую питоновский скрипт, что через bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что все приложения, которым нужен display manager и в принципе экран не знают какой display использовать, так как берут его из enviroment переменной. Как я вижу вы написали сервис для systemd. Внутрь конфига этого сервиса в секцию `[Service]` добавьте следующий код:
`Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0`
Это конкретно укажет куда выводить картинку. Насколько я помню в kali по-дефолту стоит xfce. Можно попробовать через штатные утилиты xfce настроить авто-запуск.

Comment: Если вдруг пользовательский сеанс окажется запущен на `DISPLAY=:1`, то случится ой

Answer (score 1):

положи скрипт в пользовательскую сессию
`~/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/test.service` - запустится вместе с рабочим столом